# program won't compile because of cscanf() and cprintf()

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks

I was thinking of trying the special console functions cscanf() and cprintf() but the following code does not compile

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
  int main()
{
     int a,b;
     cprintf("Enter two integers\n");
     cscanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
     cprintf("%d+%d=%d",a,b,a+b);
     return 0;
}
```

this is the error message:

```
undefined reference to 'cscanf'
undefined reference to 'cprintf'
```

Comment: Use `printf` and `scanf` instead. `conio.h` is ancient.

Comment: `does not compile` Compilers usually don't give you true or false responses. What's the error?

Comment: The compiler most likely tells you to use `_cprintf` and `_cscanf` instead. You could have at least tried that first.

Comment: undefined reference to 'cscanf'
undefined reference to 'cprintf'

Comment: Why did people close this as "not programming-related"? I VTC it as "no MCVE".

Comment: Your C library does not provide `cprintf` or `cscanf`. That's why your code does not compile.

Comment: From where did you get this code containing `cprintf` and `cscanf`? If it's from anything related to Turbo C, throw it away and/or forget it.

Comment: “Undefined reference” means that the linker can’t find the *definitions* (i.e., the actual machine code) for those functions.  `conio` is an *ancient* library specific to old DOS and Windows environments, and isn’t supported by `gcc`.

Comment: Curiously, the compiler didn't complain about `#include <conio.h>` ? Another user added the `gcc` tag, but my guess is that you are using The ancient Borland Turbo C.

Answer (score 2):

`gcc` does not incude the non-standard header `conio.h` or the functions it declares, When using standard C, and checking that `scanf` actually succeeded, it will look something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
     int a, b;
     printf("Enter two integers\n");
     if(scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) == 2) {
         printf("%d+%d=%d\n", a, b, a+b);
     } else {
         puts("you failed to input two integers");
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would say `"You failed to input two measly integers. Good job."`.

Comment: when I use printf() and scanf() it works just fine but when I use cprintf() and cscanf() the program does not run.I want to know what the problem could be.

Comment: @JL2210 :-) One could even create a generator for random insults.

Comment: @SportsTV `conio.h` and the functions it declares are not part of standard C. You should add a tag to your question for the specific environment you are using.

Comment: I use Code Block ide and the compiler is GNU GCC compiler

Comment: @SportsTV What people are trying to tell you is that the problem is that `cprintf` and `cprintf` are obsolete.  (They were never Standard in the first place.) They don't work for you because the (modern) compiler you're usng today doesn't support them.  Only a relatively few, very old, now-obsolete compilers supported them.

Comment: @SportsTV take a look at this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h, if you are using gcc as a compile, the compiler does not support `conio.h`.  Actually if I were you, I'd forget that `conio.h` ever existed and stick to standard C

Comment: @SportsTV I added the tags for `gcc` and `codeblocks` to your question. You can however edit your question yourself to add information after you've posted it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo OP can't have been using gcc (your added tag) because the compiler would have given an error for `#include <conio.h>`.

Comment: @WeatherVane OP wrote that he/she uses `gcc`. The header could possibly be residue from another environment or something OP downloaded with hopes that it would work. Both would explain why gcc gives linking errors.